# Azure devops PowerShell task to create bug when pipeline fails is failing with error Page not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Set the URL for the REST API to create a new work item

```
          $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/Abc/Def/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=6.1-preview.3" 
          echo $uri
          # Set the personal access token (PAT) for authentication
          $pat = "U2hyayuty43f4y32tfytf23ytf"
          $headers = @{
            "Authorization" = "Basic $pat"
            "Content-Type" = "application/json-patch+json"
          }
          # Create the JSON payload for the new defect work item
          $defectPayload = @"
          [
           {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.Title",
            "from": null,
            "value": "Test of REST functionality"
           },
           {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.State",
            "from": null,
            "value": "New"
           }
           ]
          "@
          

          # Create the new defect work item
          Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body ($defectPayload|ConvertTo-Json)
```

It's working in postman but in azure pipeline failing with error:
Page not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$bug` here wants to be a variable:

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/Abc/Def/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=6.1-preview.3"
```

try this:

```
$uri = 'https://dev.azure.com/Abc/Def/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=6.1-preview.3'
```

Comment: Now i am getting the below error:

Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass 
a valid patch document in the body of the request.","typeName":"Microsoft.Visua
lStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.
Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"even
tId":3000}

Tried giving the below code:
              # Create the new defect work item
              Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $defectPayload) -UseDefaultCredentials

Comment: @ShriyaSoni you do not need this `$defectPayload|ConvertTo-Json` just pass `-Body $defectPayload`